# How to count how many times a value is in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am building a function that I would like to creates a random 20x20 array consisting of the values 0, 1 and 2. I would secondly like to iterate through the array and keep a count of how many of each number are in the array. Here is my code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random 

def my_array():

  rand_array = np.random.randint(0,3,(20,20))

  zeros = 0
  ones = 0
  twos = 0

  for element in rand_array:
    if element == 0:
        zeros += 1
    elif element == 1:
        ones += 1
    else:
        twos += 1

  return rand_array,zeros,ones,twos


print(my_array())
```

When I eliminate the for loop to try and iterate the array it works fine and prints the array however as is, the code gives this error message:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it necessary you explicitly iterate through the array, e.g. homework condition, or are you okay with Python taking care of the loops under the hood?

Answer (score 4):

When you iterate on a multi-dimensional `numpy` array, you're only iterating over the first dimension. In your example, your `element` values will be 1-dimensional arrays too!

You could solve the issue with another `for` loop over the values of the 1-dimensional array, but in `numpy` code, using `for` loops is very often a bad idea. You usually want to be using vector operations and operations broadcast across the whole array instead.

In your example, you could do:

```
rand_array = np.random.randint(0,3,(20,20))

# no loop needed
zeros = np.sum(rand_array == 0)
ones = np.sum(rand_array == 1)
twos = np.sum(rand_array == 2)
```

The `==` operator is broadcast over the whole array producing an boolean array. Then the `sum` adds up the `True` values (`True` is equal to `1` in Python) to get a count.

Comment: Unless someone is required to explicitly iterate through the array, **this** is the way to do it; easy, simple, clear and efficient.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out you are iterating over the rows, not the elements. And `numpy` just refuses to evaluate the truth of an `array` except the array only contains one element.

## Iteration over all elements

If you want to iterate over each element I would suggest using [`np.nditer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html). That way you access every element regardless of how many dimensions your array has. You just need to alter this line:

```
for element in np.nditer(rand_array):
# instead of "for element in rand_array:"
```

## An alternative using a histogram

But I think there is an even better approach: If you have an array containing discrete values (like integer) you could use [`np.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) to get your counts.

You need to setup the bins so that every integer will have it's own bin:

```
bins = np.arange(np.min(rand_array)-0.5, np.max(rand_array)+1.5) 
# in your case this will give an array containing [-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5]
```

This way the histogram will fill the first bin with every value between `-0.5` and `0.5` (so every `0` of your array), the second bin with all values between `0.5` and `1.5` (every `1`), and so on. Then you call the histogram function to get the counts:

```
counts, _ = np.histogram(rand_array, bins=bins)
print(counts) # [130 145 125] # So 130 zeros, 145 ones, 125 twos
```

This approach has the advantage that you don't need to hardcode your values (because they will be calculated within the `bins`).

---

As indicated in the comments, you don't need to setup the bins as `float`. You could use simple `integer`-bins:

```
bins = np.arange(np.min(rand_array), np.max(rand_array)+2) 
# [0 1 2 3]
counts, _ = np.histogram(rand_array, bins=bins)
print(counts) # [130 145 125]
```

Comment: Great use of the histogram function. Using a float range is somewhat overkill given the input is an int array, but I guess it's more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop iterates through the rows, so you have to insert another loop for every row:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random 

def my_array():

    rand_array = np.random.randint(0,3,(20,20))


    zeros = 0
    ones = 0
    twos = 0

    for element in rand_array:
        for el in element:
            if el == 0:
                zeros += 1
            elif el == 1:
                ones += 1
            else:
                twos += 1

    return rand_array,zeros,ones,twos




    return rand_array



print(my_array())
```